# jQuery: Breaking away from nested functions

Tags: jquery

I'm creating a dashboard that is running great. The last step is to create a "user guide" of how-to's.  I decided to create a drop down help menu attached to the top link bar.  Being new to jQuery/JavaScript I am struggling with the workflow.  Although I've been able to prototype what I want to do, it only works in one direction meaning I can navigate to the article chosen, but when going back to the table of contents it no longer lets me navigate the links.

This makes sense because I use the nested code, which I do not know how to write any other way:

```
// TOGGLE DROP DOWN
$('.userguide').click(function() {

    // FIRST LOAD OF TABLE OF CONTENTS
    $('.guide_box').load('includes/guide/table_of_contents.php', function() {
        $('.guide_container').slideToggle('slow');

        // CHOOSE LINK FROM TABLE OF CONTENTS
        $('.guide_link').click(function() {
            $('.guide_box').load('includes/guide/creating_jobs.php', function() {

                // BACK BUTTON TO TABLE OF CONTENTS
                $('.backlink').click(function() {
                    $('.guide_box').load('includes/guide/table_of_contents.php');
                });

            });
        });

    });
});
```

My HTML is simply:

```
<div class="header">
   <ul class="hidden-phone">
      <li>
        <a class="userguide" href="#"><span class="fs1" aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe03b;"></span> User Guide</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>

    <div class="guide_container">
        <div class="guide_pointer"></div>
        <div class="guide_box"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here are a couple photos to illustrate what I am trying to build:

Table of Contents: [Click to view image](http://tinypic.com/r/ranuvs/5)

After clicking a link: [Click to view image](http://tinypic.com/r/9atsg9/5)

**How would I go about writing my jQuery code in a non-nested way that allows me to continue to bounce back and forth between table of contents and article?  Thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your functions elsewhere and just call them where you wire up your event handlers:

```
// TOGGLE DROP DOWN
$('.userguide').click(toggleDropdown);

function toggleDropdown() {
    // FIRST LOAD OF TABLE OF CONTENTS
    $('.guide_box').load('includes/guide/table_of_contents.php', wireGuideContainer);
}

function wireGuideContainer() {
    $('.guide_container').slideToggle('slow');

    // CHOOSE LINK FROM TABLE OF CONTENTS
    $('.guide_link').click(loadCreatingJobs);
}

function loadCreatingJobs() {
    $('.guide_box').load('includes/guide/creating_jobs.php', wireBackButton);
}

function wireBackButton() {
    // BACK BUTTON TO TABLE OF CONTENTS
    $('.backlink').click(loadTableOfContents);
}

function loadTableOfContents() {
    $('.guide_box').load('includes/guide/table_of_contents.php');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just needed a little guidance and your answer was perfect - with a little modification, it is now working.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sure thing. Good luck! =D

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this using event delegation, which allows you to bind event handlers before the elements exist:

```
$(document).on('click', '.userguide', function() {
    $('.guide_box').load('includes/guide/table_of_contents.php'); 
});

$(document).on('click', '.guide_box', function() {
    $('.guide_container').slideToggle('slow');
});

$(document).on('click', '.guide_link', function() {
    $('.guide_box').load('includes/guide/creating_jobs.php');
});

$(document).on('click', '.backlink', function() {
    $('.guide_box').load('includes/guide/table_of_contents.php');
});
```